# JDBC transactions Oracle Weblogic

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic12c

I'm making use of Oracle Weblogic's JNDI datasource for connection pooling. I'm creating a new connection for every method that is being called. My problem is that if one the method throws an Exception, I want all the other connections in the previous methods to get rolled back.

```
    private void insertA() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection con = DbUtils.getConnection()) {
            // insert into table A
        }
    }

    private void insertB() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection con = DbUtils.getConnection()) {
            // insert into table B
        }
    }

    private void insertC() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection con = DbUtils.getConnection()) {
            // insert into table C
        }
    }

    public void insertData() throws SQLException {
        insertA();
        insertB();
        insertC();
    }
```

Comment: All your insert methods must share the same jdbc connection.
The connection should be reserved and released in your insertData method.

Comment: What if some of the methods take more than 20 seconds to execute? In general it's not considered good practice to hold a connection for that amount of time.

Comment: If your process runs more than 20 seconds you may have a design issue.
If all these methods must run in the same transaction they should share the same connection. 
Distributed transactions (XA) are suitted for handling several connections in the same transaction but requires more configuration and are less fast.